# How to fix this: renv package complains that a package is missing it DESCRIPTION file

Tags: r, renv

When I launch R, the renv package complains:

```
- Project '~/Dropbox/StatsBook6' loaded. [renv 1.0.5]
The following package(s) are missing their DESCRIPTION files:
- digest [/Users/mk/Dropbox/StatsBook6/renv/library/R-4.3/aarch64-apple-darwin20/digest]
These may be left over from a prior, failed installation attempt.
Consider removing or reinstalling these packages.
```

In the above-mentioned folder, I see three items:

- digest [a folder, 0 bytes]
- digest (Michael Kubovy's conflicted copy 2024-03-15 1) [a symbolic link to a folder, 139 bytes]
- digest (Michael Kubovy's conflicted copy 2024-03-15) [same as previous]

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the package and re-install with `renv::remove` and `renv::install`?

Comment: Looks more like an Rstudio warning. Rstudio supports “projects” while I’ve never seen that term in ordinary R package maintenance contexts.

Comment: @LMc: yes. I run renv::status() and get the same as before PLUS:
The following package(s) are in an inconsistent state:

 package                                                                       installed recorded used
 digest                                                                                      n         n        y   
 digest (Michael Kubovy's conflicted copy 2024-03-15 2) y         n        y

Comment: What does `file.exists(r"(/Users/mk/Dropbox/StatsBook6/renv/library/R-4.3/aarch64-apple-darwin20/digest/DESCRIPTION)")` return?

Comment: file.exists(r"(/Users/mk/Dropbox/StatsBook6/renv/library/R-4.3/aarch64-apple-darwin20/digest/DESCRIPTION)")
[1] FALSE